# pandas time_range does not start from start date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I recently started using pandas and I have some issue regarding date_range.

```
In [168]: pd.date_range("2013-07-01", "2013-10-03", freq='W').to_series()
Out[168]: 
2013-07-07   2013-07-07
2013-07-14   2013-07-14
2013-07-21   2013-07-21
2013-07-28   2013-07-28
2013-08-04   2013-08-04
2013-08-11   2013-08-11
2013-08-18   2013-08-18
2013-08-25   2013-08-25
2013-09-01   2013-09-01
2013-09-08   2013-09-08
2013-09-15   2013-09-15
2013-09-22   2013-09-22
2013-09-29   2013-09-29
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

in the above example I expected the first index to be `2013-07-01` not `2013-07-07`. I checked and see that by default date_range consider both closed right and left. Also tried some other frequencies like `W-MON`, but didnt help.

Comment: Possibly a bug that has been fixed. `pd.date_range("2013-07-01", "2013-10-03", freq='W-MON')` gives the correct `[2013-07-01, ..., 2013-09-30]` for me (I'm on master). What's your pandas version?

Comment: @TomAugspurger I'm using 0.13.1 version

Comment: @TomAugspurger you are right. it works by W-MON. it seems i didnt check this one. can you tell me the reason?

Comment: date_range is strict, so it will never create a date outside the `start` and `stop` params. By default its anchored to Sunday, which was the 7th of that first month.

Answer (score 1):

8 years later, version 1.5.2 still the same bug:

```py
my_period = pd.date_range('2015-09-01', '2016-07-01', freq='3M')
my_period
```

gives

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-03-31', '2016-06-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3M')
```

By default start should be anchored to the given date IMHO, here the first of September 2015 at 00h00. The story of the Sunday does not work here.

Funny fact, if I add an hour, it uses it correctly, but the day is still incorrect:

```py
my_period = pd.date_range('2015-09-01 02:10', '2016-07-01', freq='3M')
my_period

DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-30 02:10:00', '2015-12-31 02:10:00',
               '2016-03-31 02:10:00', '2016-06-30 02:10:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3M')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='2023-09-13', freq = 'W', periods=3)
Date
0 2023-09-17
1 2023-09-24
2 2023-10-01
```

The issue is still there

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35261506)

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) pandas docs, it's noted that

> When using the offset aliases above, it should be noted that functions such as date_range(), bdate_range(), will only return timestamps that are in the interval defined by start_date and end_date. If the start_date does not correspond to the frequency, the returned timestamps will start at the next valid timestamp, same for end_date, the returned timestamps will stop at the previous valid timestamp.

If you scroll down a bit you would see you can use [Anchored Offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets).

You can use the `time` module to figure out what day of the week was the date specified and than use it as offset.

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

start_time = time.strptime("2013-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d")

print(pd.date_range("2013-07-01", "2013-10-03", freq=f'W-{time.strftime("%a", start_time)}').to_series())
```

Which outputs:

```
2013-07-01   2013-07-01
2013-07-08   2013-07-08
2013-07-15   2013-07-15
2013-07-22   2013-07-22
2013-07-29   2013-07-29
2013-08-05   2013-08-05
2013-08-12   2013-08-12
2013-08-19   2013-08-19
2013-08-26   2013-08-26
2013-09-02   2013-09-02
2013-09-09   2013-09-09
2013-09-16   2013-09-16
2013-09-23   2013-09-23
2013-09-30   2013-09-30
Freq: W-MON, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```