# pandas date_range, end karg

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Long time reader, 1st question, new to pandas, hope the question makes sense !
I have a DataFrame df indexed by :

```
In [151]: df.index
Out[151]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-08-04, ..., 2040-08-04]
Length: 37, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I'd like a new DataFrame containing all the values df already has, and NaN for all the quarterly dates that begin the quarter following the first date in df, and ending the quarter following the last date in df.

My plan is to :

1. build a DataFrame containing the quarterly indexes
2. concat it with my df DataFrame

So I did :

```
In [163]: dfm=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=df.index[0],end=df.index[len(df)-1],freq='Q'))

In [164]: dfs=pd.concat([df,dfm]).sort()

In [165]: dfs.tail()
Out[165]: 
                        NPV
2040-03-31              NaN
2040-06-30              NaN
2040-07-30  31977750.393512
2040-08-04  30000000.000000
2040-08-04  30000000.000000

[5 rows x 1 columns]
```

The issue is that the last quarter is 2040-06-30 and not 2040-09-30.
So the end keyword in `date_range` apparently sets the quarter preceeding `df.index[len(df)-1]`, is there a way to tell `date-range` to use the quarter following ?

Comment: Try with `closed='right'` on the call to `date_range`.

Comment: unfortunately : 
`In [38]: pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2014-04-08',end='2040-08-04',freq='Q')).tail()
Out[38]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2039-06-30 00:00:00, 2039-09-30 00:00:00, 2039-12-31 00:00:00, 2040-03-31 00:00:00, 2040-06-30 00:00:00]

[5 rows x 0 columns]

In [40]: pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2014-04-08',end='2040-08-04',freq='Q',closed='right')).tail()
Out[40]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2039-06-30 00:00:00, 2039-09-30 00:00:00, 2039-12-31 00:00:00, 2040-03-31 00:00:00, 2040-06-30 00:00:00]
`

Comment: `pd.date_range(start=df.index[0],end=df.index[len(df)-1]+pd.datetools.QuarterEnd(1),freq='Q')` is what I came up with, would like to know if there is something simpler as according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108818/pandas-time-range-does-not-start-from-start-date end and start keywords are strictly inclusive

Comment: I think this is a good solution, as `date_range` will never return values outside start/end dates (which was the case in your example)